# SwiftUI: Why Is an Extension Used for a Custom Struct (Apple iOS App Dev Tutorial)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

In the Apple [iOS App Dev Tutorial] (as of Jan 22)(https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training), under the [Creating a Navigation Hierarchy](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/creating-a-navigation-hierarchy) section, we extend a struct that we have defined.

I have tried reading the [Swift documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html) about extensions, but don't really understand why this is done here. The documentation talks about extending system types such as adding extra properties to the system type `Double`, but not adding extra properties to something that we have full control over, such as our own structure.

I am sure it is a best practice, as this is an Apple tutorial, but they don't really do a good job of explaining it.

This is an example of the code they want you to write:

```
import SwiftUI

struct DailyScrum: Identifiable  {
    let id: UUID
    var title: String
    var attendees: [Attendee]
    var lengthInMinutes: Int
    var theme: Theme
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), title: String, attendees: [String], lengthInMinutes: Int, theme: Theme) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.attendees = attendees.map { Attendee(name: $0) }
        self.lengthInMinutes = lengthInMinutes
        self.theme = theme
    }
}

extension DailyScrum {
    struct Attendee: Identifiable {
        let id: UUID
        var name: String
        
        init(id: UUID = UUID(), name: String) {
            self.id = id
            self.name = name
        }
    }
}
```

I am uncertain why the `Attendee` structure has to be defined within an extension. For example, this works too:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Attendee: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    var name: String
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct DailyScrum: Identifiable  {
    let id: UUID
    var title: String
    var attendees: [Attendee]
    var lengthInMinutes: Int
    var theme: Theme
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), title: String, attendees: [String], lengthInMinutes: Int, theme: Theme) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.attendees = attendees.map { Attendee(name: $0) }
        self.lengthInMinutes = lengthInMinutes
        self.theme = theme
    }
}
```

I'm just not sure why you would do one over the other.

Comment: I think this is just because this is a multi-step tutorial. They define `DailyScrum` at some earlier step, and then extend it as needed in following steps. (for instance you could find another extension with "sample data" at [this step](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/displaying-data-in-a-list)). I believe this wouldn't be necessary in a real-world app.

Comment: @tromgy it’s still pretty good practice, it keeps things naturally grouped together

Comment: It also stops unnecessary access to the Attendee type without making it explicit that they're a DailyScrum.Attendee which improves code clarity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is styling and also focuses the code in this case

Your type as originally written is

```
DailyScrum.Attendee
```

If you change it to the second version you will have 2 separate independent types.

```
Attendee
```

and

```
DailyScrum
```

Without looking at the tutorial I would assume that there is another type of `Attendee`. Such as..

```
Conference.Attendee
```

or

```
WeeklyScrum.Attendee
```

But as you pointed out this would only make sense if they are different like a Homonym. Some samples are...

```
Bird.Crane
Construction.Crane
```

or

```
Dog.Bark
Tree.Bark
```

If all you are using is an `id` and a `name` there is no point to have a separate data structure.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you. Based on your answer, it seems like structs act like namespaces in C# or something similar. I’ve just not come across code in which a struct has been defined within a struct and accessed as you have demonstrated.

Comment: Kind of, there are name spaces in swift too but a similar  concept. I haven’t put a struct in a struct either but I use extensions a lot for cleanliness. I put delegates in them quite a bit.

Comment: Why is `Attendee` defined in an `extension` rather than the original `struct`?

Comment: @indirectlylit it is a preference, a lot of seasoned developers use `extension` for organization. When models/code base gets large it is an easy way to find code that is all related.

Comment: I see. So, sort of like adding a comment above a block of code that says `/*** Utilities ***/`? That would make some sense, but it's surprising to me that it's not labeled or named with the purpose...

Comment: @indirectlylit yes, I would use `// MARK: Utilities` but yes. One big advantage is different files such as `DailyScrum.swift` and `DailyScrum+Attendee.swift`.  or something like `NetworkingService.swift` and `Networking+Database.swift` and `Networking+Authentication`, etc. Each "subtype" or `extension` can be large and having all that in one object or file can become a nightmare for longevity sake.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I can see that it would be hard to break a single object definition across multiple files without using `extension`, and in that case the filename provides the meaningful label.

Answer (score 1):

In the tutorial, I believe that it is a pattern choice so that the data model more closely mirrors the SwiftUI layout for ease of understanding.

Attendees only appear as a child view of the detailView using ForEach(...) to generate a VStack. Therefore, in this case, where MVVM isn't being used, it makes sense to clearly map the data model to the view, and make it explicit in the code pattern that the Attendee type only occurs within an instance of a DailyScrum, just as attendees details only appear within the detailView.